# javascript click back twice showing strange results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

In my jquery mobile page, I have a page menu page A, then when you click the button to see profile, it goes to profile page B, then you can click edit and it takes you to edit page C. Upon the ajax return from saving the form, I want to return to page A again by using code to click back twice.

I have that below, but the problem is, it works the first time, then when I go back in the form and save, what happens is it goes back 4 times, then if I try again goes back like 4 or 5 times. It's not going back twice always for some reason.

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks

```
$("#profile-edit-form").find("input[type=submit]").click(function(){

    var formData = $(this).parent().parent().serialize();
    formData += '&page=setprofile&id=' + user['id'];

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/site/script/sqlhandler.php',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(jsonData) {
            handleResponse(jsonData, function(response) {
                window.history.go(-2);
            });
        },
        error: function(data,status,xhr) {
            alert('Error Occured!');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Consider using a router instead of hardcoding history jumps. http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/ or https://github.com/tildeio/router.js/

Comment: that seems kinda overkill for this problem. I guess I could manually switch to that page..

Comment: I mean yeah exactly: If you know you are trying to get back to page A then why not just explicitly jump to page A?

Comment: one issue is that  by then clicking back from page A, it would take you to page C which is weird...